# How to change each line of texts color using css

Tags: css

How do I change the color of each individual line in this scenario to the color specified. I keep changing all the text to either one of these colors but cant seem to separate each line to its specified color.

```
<p>This text is red.</p>
<p>This text is blue.</p>
<p>This text is green.</p>
```

Comment: Can you change the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple tag `<p>` with a `class` like:

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}
.blue{
  color:blue;
}
.green{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<p class='red'>This text is red.</p>

<p class='blue'>This text is blue.</p>

<p class='green'>This text is green.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to affect the color by line number you can use pseudo class `:nth-child(number)`

```css
p:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>This text is red.</p>
<p>This text is blue.</p>
<p>This text is green.</p>
```

Comment: While I agree this can be a working approach, it must be said that this highly depends on the HTML structure. If these `p` elements have any previous siblings, it will have to be adjusted. `p:nth-of-type()` might be a little more resilient, although basically suffering from the same coupling of HTML structure and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to make the color more dynamic:

```css
/* Best practice to define CSS Variables in :root */
:root {
  --color: black;
}

/* Base CSS class */
.colorify {
  color: var(--color);
}

/* Specialize implementations of the .colorify CSS class */
.colorify.colorify-blue { --color: blue; }
.colorify.colorify-red { --color: red; }
.colorify.colorify-green { --color: green; }
.colorify.colorify-brown { --color: brown; }
```

```html
<p class="colorify" style="--color: red;">
  This text is red because of CSS variable on <code>p</code>.
</p>
<p class="colorify colorify-blue">
  This text is blue because of <code>colorify-blue</code>.
</p>
<p class="colorify">
  This text is black because of the default value for the CSS Variable <code>--color</code>.
</p>
<p class="colorify colorify-green">
  This text is green, but <span class="colorify colorify-brown">this is brown</span>.
</p>
```